# render jsp content based on javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have to render a column of a table in jsp. Now, this jsp page is being used in one other page also. That particular column should come up only in other page, not in my page. So for this i am using one context variable, which i am getting somehow and saving it in my javascript value.

how to do this ?

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function getPageId(){
            var someValue = fetching it some how using url.
            var pageId=someValue;  
        }
    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript">getPageId();</script>
</head>



<body>
    <table id="pageContent" width="100%" valign="top">
    <tr>
        <td id="firstColumn">
             <div class="className">
                 <jsp:include page="/pages/common/blank.jsp" />
             </div>
        </td>

        <td id="secondColumn" width="100%" style="padding-left:16px">
                   
        </td>
    </tr>
            </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Column td with id="firstCoulmn" has to get conditionally rendered based on value of pageId variable

Please help

Comment: JavaScript is client-side scripting, which operates in the browser after JSP generates the HTML. How could you use a variable from the JS context that does not even exist (yet) in JSP?

Comment: can you explain the logic of `var someValue = fetching it some how using url`. ?

Comment: you can't use javascript to prevent jsp render, you can do the opposite use a jsp variable to render a part of the page with an if statement.
With javascript you can hide/strip the div but only post rendering so you will have it in page at the start.

Comment: @vjy That somevalue is the value of pageId which i am fetching from context parameters. That is not a problem. Issue comes after that.

Answer (score 0):

If `var someValue` can be determined by the url parameter, then you have to do the logic in the server side itself.

```
<body>
<table id="pageContent" width="100%" valign="top">
<tr>
<% 
String someValue = request.getParameter("someValue");

// Your logic goes here
if("test".equals(someValue)) {   %>

<td id="firstColumn">
             <div class="className">
                 <jsp:include page="/pages/common/blank.jsp" />
             </div>
        </td>

<% } %>
<td id="secondColumn" width="100%" style="padding-left:16px">

        </td>
    </tr>
            </table>
</body>
```